# Need a distinct count of VehicleID's for each day in Power BI table

Tags: powerbi

I have a table in Power Bi and I would to create a new column like in my example table "VehicleID DistictCount" that **counts each VehicleID one time for each day** and enters a 0 for all other occurances.

This table shows the results for the month.

I have  tried many different formulas and measures with no luck. I even tried ChatGPT but the code did not work.

Thank you for your help

[image]